# Uniqueness of a continuous function

Tags: general-topology

> Let $A\subset X$ ;let $f:A\to Y$ be continuous ;let $Y$ be Hausdorff. Show that if $f$ may be extended to a continuous function $g:\overline A\to Y$ then $g$ is uniquely determined.

**My try:**
Let $h(x)$ be another such function.

Suppose $h(x)\neq g(x)$ for some $x\in \overline A\setminus A$ .Then since $Y$ is Hausdorff;$\exists $ open sets $W_1,W_2$ such that $h(x)\in W_1;g(x)\in W_2$ and $W_1\cap W_2=\varnothing $.

By continuity of $h,g,\exists $ open sets $U,V\in X$ containing $x$ such that $h(U)\subset W_1;g(V)\subset W_2$.

Also $U\cap A\neq \varnothing ,V\cap A\neq \varnothing $.let $x_1\in U\cap A ;x_2\in V\cap A$.

So $h(x_1)=f(x_1)\in h(U)\subset W_1;g(x_2)=f(x_2)\in g(V)\subset W_2$.

How to reach a contradiction from here?Please help me to complete this one without taking another approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need a point $x_3 \in U \cap V$, where $g$ and $h$ agree. Note that $U \cap V$ is an open set containing $x$ and we have $h[U\cap V] \subseteq W_1$ and $g[U\cap V] \subseteq W_2$. As $W_1 \cap W_2 = \emptyset$, for $x_3 \in A \cap (U \cap V)$, we have $g(x_3) \ne h(x_3)$. On the other side, $x_3 \in A \cap U$ and $x_3 \in A \cap V$. Can you conclude?